# weird quirk: pushState and/or hashChange clear the title from the browser tab

Tags: javascript, pushstate, history.js, hashchange

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 app that I have built as a single page app that following the example(s) in the [BigShelf SPA](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Single-Page-d6d7172c) using Knockout.js and History.js to handle user interaction and navigation. Everything works fine, but I'm noticing a weird quirk with the title being displayed in the browser tab:

1. When the app loads, the browser tab title properly displays the content of the `<title>` tag, i.e., `My Single Page App`
2. When History.js uses either `pushState` or `hashChange` (depending on the capability of the browser) to modify the URL, the browser's tab title is set to the newly modified URL, i.e., the browser tab now reads `http://www.mysinglepageapp.com/modified/url`

Again, functionally there's no problem, but it's odd to me that the tab title is also modified. This is happening in all browsers that I've tested (IE6+, FF, Chrome, Safari).

Is their anyway to change or control this behavior?

Comment: Isn't this the default behaviour of that library, that it changes document.title as well? You'd need to set one, else the URL would be used.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the hint. You're right and it turns out the wrapper around History.js used in the SPA was setting the title to the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off of Bergi's comment, I took a closer look at History.js and the wrapper provided in the BigShelf SPA example.

Turns out that History.js provides a method that accepts a parameter of which title should be displayed `history.pushState(params, title, url)`. The wrapper in the SPA passes the url as the title. I changed that to the name of my app and that solved the "issue".